# AttributeError: 'Chat' object has no attribute 'converse'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
#SLINNINGBOT 2.0#

import nltk.chat
import sys
import os
import time
import platform
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
import re
import random
from nltk import compat

what = platform.system()
now = time.time()
means = time.ctime(now)



class Chat(object):
    def converse(self, quit="quit"):
            input = ""
            while input != quit:
                input = quit
                try: input = compat.raw_input(">")
                except EOFError:
                    print(input)
                if input:
                    while input[-1] in "!.": input = input[:-1]
                    print(self.respond(input))

    slinning_chatbot = Chat(pairs, reflections)

    def slinning_chat():
        print "WELCOME"
        print "OPERATIONAL SYSTEM:",what
        print "\nTIME IS NOW",now
        print "WHICH INTERPRETS AS",means
        print "PLEASE BE AWARE THAT THIS BOT IS UNDER DEVELOPMENT AND MAY BE FAULTY"
        print"======================================================================="
        print"Please fill the input"

        slinning_chatbot.converse()
    def demo():
        slinning_chat()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        demo()
```

I just extracted the parts of the code that i believe actually matters here, i have no idea why im getting error: AttributeError: 'Chat' object has no attribute 'converse'

Please hit me up if you need the entire code, its pretty long though

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: Rename class Chat to something else as it will conflict with the import `from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections`

Comment: @Pavan Correct! Thank you very much, this is the correct answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code executes before the `Chat` class has been fully defined, therefore it is attempting to use `nltk.chat.util.Chat`. Dedent the parts you want to run *after* the class has been defined, and avoid reusing names.

Comment: Im sorry, forgot to paste the part where the chat class ends, but the problem was that the class conflicted with the import. Thank you for your time anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening was because the import was conflicting with the class, due to both having the same name